# Loading an image from a form to a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I'm uploading images from a form to a RecyclerView. I have created in such a way that if I hit the "+" button let me place it let me place a gallery image and or taken from the camera.

But besides this, for the Spinner, I have assigned to him that each element of the list assigns him an image by default that I have loaded it through Glide:

```
spTypePets.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Resources res = getResources();
        String spinner = spTypePets.getSelectedItem().toString();

        switch (position) {

            case 0:

                Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.dog).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                break;

            case 1:

                Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.cat).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                break;

            case 2:

                Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.mouse).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                break;

            case 3:

                Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.fish).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                break;

            case 4:

                Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.birds).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                break;

            case 5:

                Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.reptile).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                break;

            case 6:

                Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.other).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                break;

        }

    }
```

So far so good, the problem is that now I need to load also that image by default when creating an object of the type "Pet" through this form, ie: if you do not take any photo, you leave the photo by default and can upload it.

```
 btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            realm.beginTransaction();

            Pets pet = new Pets();

            pet.setPetName(etPetName.getText().toString());
            pet.setPetType(petTypeLst.get(spTypePets.getSelectedItemPosition()));
            pet.setPetUrlImage(imagePath);

            Number maxId = realm.where(Pets.class).max("id");
            long nextID;

            if (maxId == null) {
                nextID = 1;
            } else {
                nextID = maxId.longValue() + 1;
            }

            pet.setId(nextID);

            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(pet);
            realm.commitTransaction();

            finish();

        }
    });
```

I know that besides Glide as I'm saving it, I must also save it in "Pet" so it can be added, but I have no idea how. See if you can give me a hand. Thank you very much.

Greetings.

Comment: _"Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema es que ahora necesito cargar también esa imagen por defecto al crear un objeto del tipo "Pet" a través de dicho formulario, es decir: si no hace ninguna foto, que salga la foto por defecto y pueda cargarla._" **English please**.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to translate that part hahaha.

Comment: so if imagePath is null, it should upload default image, otherwise it should upload the specific drawable?

Comment: Exactly, that's the idea, but I've been trying and I can't store the default image to pass it through the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to convert `R.drawable` to `String`, then assign them to `imagePath`.

**Example**

```
spTypePets.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Resources res = getResources();
        String spinner = spTypePets.getSelectedItem().toString();

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
              imagePath = getURLForResource(R.drawable.dog);
              Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.dog).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
                break;
                     ......
            }   
      }

public String getURLForResource (int resourceId) {
    return Uri.parse("android.resource://"+R.class.getPackage().getName()+"/" +resourceId).toString();
 }
```

When `btnSave` is clicked, check whether if `imagePath` is null. If it is null, pass the default image. Make sure you convert the default image to `String` before you pass.